# What clock is used on macOS to return the value for SO_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, posix

Since I could not find any documentation, does anyone know what clock is used on macOS to return value for ancillary header `SCM_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC` when `SO_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC` is set? From tests, seems that it could be `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` which would make sense, but it could also be `CLOCK_UPTIME_RAW` but that would be a weird choice since it does not advance during sleep? I assume that for `SO_TIMESTAMP` the return of `gettimeofday` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `SO_TIMESTAMP` is set, `getmicrotime()` is used.
When `SO_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC` is set, `mach_absolute_time()` is used.

Source: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.61.1/bsd/netinet/ip_input.c

Comment: I stumbled upon this when googling, but I could not understand if these are the actual kernel sources, thanks.

Comment: Btw, the `getmicrotime` macro and `microtime` funciton is in kernel framwork headers, are they even supposed to be accessed from userspace?

Comment: They are part of the kernel interface. I wouldn't expect them to be available in user space.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis `getmicrotime()` in the kernel is equivalent to `gettimeofday()` in userspace